# Java codes giving error after proper allocation of memory

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm trying to print the value of each pixel, but it gives error when `p = 300`.
Before `p = 300`, all pixels are printed.

`orignal.getHeight() = 344;` and `orignal.getWidth() = 300;`.

```
BufferedImage binarized = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), original.getType());
int p, q;

System.out.println(original.getHeight() + "," + original.getWidth());

for(p=0;p<original.getHeight();p++)
{
    for(q = 0; q < original.getWidth(); q++)
    {
        //System.out.println("goint to get pixel"+"("+p+","+q+")");
        int Pixel = binarized.getRGB(p, q);
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(ByteInterleavedRaster.java:318)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:888)
    at Binarization.binarize(Binarization.java:137)
        at Binarization.main(Binarization.java:20)
```

Is this some kind of memory allocation problem?

Comment: What line is line 137 or line 20 in `Binarization`?  Post your complete class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this means that you have an error in your logic.

You try to access an array element by index, which is greater than array size

Try changing the logic of the array retrieval:

```
 int Pixel=binarized.getRGB(q,p);
```

This works because the method expects: getRGB(int width,int height), but you provide height, width to it

Comment: but I printer array size it is greater than 300.(binarized.Height()=344 and binarized.Width()=300) . and I am getting error at (300,1)

Comment: you have 2 arrays, check the size of both

Comment: this works because the method expects: getRGB(int width,int height), but you provide height, width to it

Comment: @Funtik: Well, it expects (x, y) - not (width, height).

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, it all depends on how you define the x / y axis

Comment: @Funtik: No, it really doesn't. width and height are the width and height of the image; x and y are values identifying a point *within* the image. That's why the parameters are actually called x and y, not width and height. (Check the docs.)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for [`BufferedImage.getRGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29)

```
public int getRGB(int x, int y)
```

Note that the `x` value is the first parameter - *that's* the one which should be in the range [0, width). The `y` value is the second parameter - that's the one which should be in the range [0, height). You've got them the wrong way round. I'm slightly disappointed that the exception isn't friendlier, admittedly.

It would be much clearer if you'd use `x` and `y` variables in your loop, too:

```
for (int y = 0; y < original.getHeight(); y++)
{                   
    for (int x = 0; x < original.getWidth(); x++)
    {                   
        int pixel = binarized.getRGB(x, y);
        // Use pixel
    }                   
}
```

(Also note how I've declared `x` and `y` in the loops themselves; there's no point in declaring them beforehand. I've also added whitespace for readability.)